# Format DataGridView TextBox Column Containing Numeric Values

Tags: c#, parsing, datagridview, int

I have a DataGridView with TextBox colums. One of the columns display record counts which are formatted as ###,###,000. The column itself isn't set to format the text, but the data is formatted when the data source is populated. The data source is a List by the way. The DataGridView merely displays everything as it gets it.

Now, I need to parse the numeric text value into a variable, which is fine by doing

```
int.Parse(data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_Record_Count"].Value.ToString())
```

but, if I have numbers reaching thousands, it displays as 1 000, because of the formatting. The formatting generates a space rather than a comma as this is how the environment has been configured. When I try to parse that value, I get an exception because of the space in the numeric value.

I have tried formatting the string value

```
int.Parse(String.Format("{0:000000000}", data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_Record_Count"].Value.ToString()))
```

and

```
int.Parse(String.Format("{0:########0}", data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_Record_Count"].Value.ToString()))
```

and all sorts of variants, but it keeps returning the space in the value, which then won't parse. I have tried replacing the space, but it is persistent. Also, the space shows ASCII keycode 63 which is supposed to be a question mark, not so? Even when I try to replace using the keycode... nothing!

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to fix it?

The complete code block I have is

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow data_grid_view_row in dgv_Migration_Files.Rows)
{
    if ((bool)data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_Select"].Value == true)
    {
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // this is only to test and see what value I get for the space character, will be removed later

        string test_str = data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_Record_Count"].Value.ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty);

        test_str = test_str.Replace(" ", "");

        for (int k = 0; k < test_str.Length; k++)
        {
            string newstr = test_str.Substring(k, 1);

            var kycode = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newstr);
        }

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        migrate.Add(new Migrate()
        {
            File_Folder = data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_File_Folder"].Value.ToString()
            ,
            File_Name = data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_File_Name"].Value.ToString()
            ,
            Record_Count = int.Parse(String.Format("{0:000000000}", data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_Record_Count"].Value.ToString()))
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the replace method didn't remove spaces as I expected to, I resorted to the below solution. This will also remove any other numeric separators irrespective of what the numeric separator has been set up as in the OS.

```
//get the numeric decimal seperator key code

string dummy_numeric = (1000).ToString(Helper.application_number_display_format);

char replace_char = (char)0;

foreach (char current_char in dummy_numeric)
{
    if (!System.Char.IsDigit(current_char))
    {
        replace_char = current_char;
        break;
    }
}

//get all the files that are selected for migration

List<Migrate> migrate = new List<Migrate>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow data_grid_view_row in dgv_Migration_Files.Rows)
{
    if ((bool)data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_Select"].Value == true)
    {
        migrate.Add(new Migrate()
        {
            File_Folder = data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_File_Folder"].Value.ToString()
            ,
            File_Name = data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_File_Name"].Value.ToString()
            ,
            Record_Count = int.Parse(data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_Record_Count"].Value.ToString().Replace(replace_char.ToString(), ""))
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple Solution:-
If space is available Remove it and then simply Parse into INT.

```
str.Replace(" ", String.Empty)


string data = data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_Record_Count"].Value.ToString().Replace(" ", String.Empty);

int.Parse(data);
```

Make it easier:-

```
int.Parse(data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_Record_Count"].Value.ToString().replace(" ", String.Empty));
```

And if you want to remove space and comma both while parsing using this Regular Expression

```
int.Parse(data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_Record_Count"].Value.ToString().replace(/[, ]+/g, " ").trim());
```

Check This Small Example First you will get Clear Idea:-

```
 string data = "1 0000";
 string result = data.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
```

Comment: I have tried all those options, the space remains... that is exactly why I am baffled?????

Comment: because replace function will do this for us now do this string data=data_grid_view_row.Cells["col_Record_Count"].Value.ToString().replace(" ", String.Empty) and let me what you are getting in data variable

Comment: Even if I read the value into a string variable and then try and format the variable, the space still remains... it seems as if the space is not recognized as a space but another character. That is why I retrieved the ASCII code of the space and it returned code 63, and right there is my confusion because code 63 on the code table is supposed to be a question mark, not a space.

Comment: String replace is working please check this in different project this two-line               string data = "1 0000";
 string result = data.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

Comment: and in your code you are using replace two time why??

Comment: I was only trying to determine if either of the replace methods would yield a different result, but they don't. As you can see from the comment in the code this is only test code which will be removed. The actual code is setting the property Record_Count

Comment: I have checked your updated answer and I have tried that. I am very familiar with the replace method, and that is why I am stumped because it is not working in this case. I think it has something to do with the fact that the value is retrieved from the DataGridView and there is something funny about it which I cannot put my finger on.

Comment: after getting value in string replace function will be work if possible let's connect through team viewer is it possible from your side i am also curious now

Comment: I would love to be able to connect through team viewer but I cannot because this is a work pc with lots of sensitive information... i WILL lose my job

Comment: ohh sorry@Bazïnga

Comment: what you are exactly getting in this variable tell me first test_str

Comment: I have found a solution. I will post it as answer in a minute... weird! Thank you for your input D-john, much appreciated!